# Is it possible to transact over multiple connections in mysql with php and curl

Tags: php, mysql, transactions

I've been tasked with creating some integration tests of APIs and am wondering if it is possible to do something like begin a transaction; curl several api calls; rollback the database.

Example pseudocode

```
begin_long_transaction();
$userId = (new CURL('user/create', $dataArr))->post();
(new CURL("user/$userId", $updateDataArr))->put();
$userData = (new CURL("user/$userId"))->get();

// assert userData is as expected
rollback_long_transaction();
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible to do that.
Normally you would mock this, but its possible to do live-API-testing.
You are working with PHP, so the tool of choice is phpUnit.

If you use phpUnit i would suggest to extend the PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase or the PHPUnit_Extensions_Database_TestCase and build a custom class with your beginLongTransaction() and rollbackLongTransaction() and a api() method.

Lets assume something like request($type, $url, $data), so you don't have to type "new Curl" so often. `$this->request('GET, '/somewhere', $data);`

There is also setUp() and tearDown() for doing stuff before and after a TestCase.

Watch for timeouts & set PHP execution time accordingly, as some tests might run into connection timeouts, due to the dependency on the external API.
You might also group your tests and run them seperatly, to avoid timeouts.

```
class MyApiTest1 extends MyCustomAPI_PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    // connection per test
    public function testSomething()
    {
        $this->useConnection($connectionName);

        $result = $this->request('GET', '/user/' . $this->getDb()->getUsername());

        $this->assertEquals(200, $result->getResponse()->getStatusCode());

        $this->closeConnection($connectionName);
    }
}

class MyApiTest2 extends MyCustomAPI_PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function setUp()
    {
        $this->useConnection($connectionName);
    }

    // connection per class
    public function testSomething()
    {
        $result = $this->request('GET', '/test');

        $this->assertEquals(200, $result->getResponse()->getStatusCode());
    }

    public function tearDown()
    {
         $this->closeConnection($connectionName);
    }
}
```

Base class for working with multiple db connections and one request method:

```
class MyCustomAPI_PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    static public $dbConnections = array();

    function setupConnections()
    {
        // foreach array(databaseName => credentials)
        {
           // create connection object
           // store connection object into array
           self::$dbConnections[$databaseName] = $connection;
        }
    }

    function getConnection($connectionName)
    {
        return self::$dbConnections[$connectionName];
    }

    function rollback($connectionName)
    {
        $con = $this->getConnection($connectionName);

        // rollback hard
        $con->deleteDatabase();
        $con->insertDatabaseSchema();
        $con->insertDatabaseData();

        // = database @fresh start
    }

    function beginTransaction($connectionName)
    {
        $con = $this->getConnection($connectionName);

        // do stuff on begin

        return $con;
    }

    function request($type, $url, $data)
    {
        // do curl request

        return $cURLdata;
    }

}
```

Comment: beginning a transaction in the setup wouldn't naturally affect the curl request as that would be a separate process. I'm not sure I follow

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I would set the connection to "static private $pdoConnection". That keeps it open for all following tests. You may want to look into the database chapter of the phpUnit manual http://phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/database.html

Comment: I've added some basic test examples and a base class for these tests. The base class is just a quick draft and contains some pseudo code elements. I hope that explains it a bit better.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you're using CURL to hit a service implemented somewhere else in your network, by a service with its own pool of MySQL database connections.

So, the answer to your question is "no."

Here's more information from another SO question.

[MySQL: Transactions across multiple threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2495628/mysql-transactions-across-multiple-threads)

Comment: So what about enabling persistent connections then serializing the connection in the first request (specified in the header or something in the first api call) and overriding the destroy so that the connection isn't isn't closed when the script ends and each middle script would re-use the connection until the final one which will roll it back? FYI: nothing else will be using the site during the test