# Redbean's transaction not working

Tags: php, mysql, transactions, redbean

I'm here today because I can't figure out what's the problem with my transactions using RedbeanPHP. I guess the problem lay with 'autocommit' value of MySQL since it's always ON.

Long story short:
 
1) `R::freeze(true);` has been issued,
2) Tried both `R::begin()` .. `R::commit()` and `R::transaction($callback)` syntax

Here is a simple Class with a test code:

```
class TestTransactions{
  public function testme($args){
    $tstname = $args;
    $src = R::findOne('batchscripts', 'batchclass = :tstname',
      array(':tstname' => $tstname));

    sleep(2);

    if($src){
      $src->alivesince = intval($src->alivesince) + 1;
      R::store($src);
    } else {
      $bean = R::dispense('batchscripts');
      $bean->batchclass = $tstname;
      $bean->alivesince = 0;
      $bean->start = R::$f->now();
      R::store($bean);
    }
  }

  public function testCallback(){
    $that = &$this;
    R::freeze(true);
    try{
      $ret2 = R::transaction(function() use ($that){
        //uncomment me to see autocommit value
        //$g = R::getAll("show global variables like 'autocommit'");
        //$g = array_pop($g);
        //var_dump($g);
        $that->testme('instance');
      });
    } catch (Exception $e){
      throw $e;
    }

  }

  public function testProcedural(){
    R::freeze(true);
    try{
      R::begin();
      $this->testme('instance2');
      R::commit();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
      R::rollback();
      throw $e;
    }

  }

  public function test(){

    $this->testCallback();
    $this->testProcedural();

  }
}
```

Running the test() function with more PHP scripts simultaneously (I've tried with 12), database entries are not correct:

I expect to have

```
batchclass: 'instance',  alivesince: 11
batchclass: 'instance2', alivesince: 11
```

instead i got

```
batchclass: 'instance',  alivesince: 7
batchclass: 'instance2', alivesince: 7
```

Or even

```
batchclass: 'instance',  alivesince: 5
batchclass: 'instance2', alivesince: 5
```

depending on the moment i run the scripts.

What am I missing here?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Seeing the problem from a different perspective, i've found what I was missing.

As stated in another post [a multithread transaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2495628/mysql-transactions-across-multiple-threads) is not applicable using MySQL. A portion of code that deals with syncronized access (as a mutex) is a must.

Leaving here the question since I think it can be usefull to other programmers.

Cheers

Comment: That link is actually irrelevant to the problem you encountered.  The problem with beans is that the data is extracted from the database, then you update the value and finally you put the new value back in the database.  In more classic RDBMS operations, you'd simply do "UPDATE test SET alivesince = alivesince + 1 WHERE ...".  The RedBeans approach prevents any concurrency control except if you start a transaction before retrieving the data, which is not only inefficient but annoying to code (and hard to maintain).