# How do I delete records based on query results

Tags: sql-delete

How to I delete records from a table which is referenced in my query for example, below is my query which returns me the correct amount of results but I then want to delete those records from the same table that is referenced in the query.

```
;with cte as (select *, 

row_number() over (partition by c.[Trust Discharge], c.[AE Admission], c.[NHS Number] 
                    order by c.[Hospital Number]) as Rn,

count(*) over (partition by c.[Trust Discharge], c.[AE Admission], c.[NHS Number]) as cntDups 
        from CommDB.dbo.tblNHFDArchive as c)

        Select * from cte

Where cte.Rn>1 and cntDups >1
```

Comment: which ones? those that `.Rn > 1` and `cntDups > 1`?

Comment: Yes I want to delete from CommDB.dbo.tblNHFDArchive where the above criteria is met.

Comment: hmm, I think what you are trying to do is answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/812512/faster-way-to-delete-matching-rows

Answer (score 1):

as you can already select the rows by querying `Select * from cte Where cte.Rn>1 and cntDups >1`, you can delete them by running `delete from your_table where unique_column in (Select unique_column from cte Where cte.Rn>1 and cntDups >1)`

note that **unique_column** is a column in your table that cannot have duplicate values, and **your_table** is the table where the rows reside.

and don't forget to backup your table first if it's on production.